# How to print from a text file into a 2D array using fgets?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//Including libraries to be used

int readMovies(FILE *file, char Names[3][50]) {

  int i;
  int j;

  FILE *file = fopen("Names.txt", "r")
  if (myFile == NULL) {
      printf("Error");
      exit(-1);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      fgets(Names[i][j], 50, file);
    }
  }

}
```

> I'm trying to print from the attached file into the array called, "Names." My first thought was using fgets, but I'm confused on how to do it if this is even the best way. How do I use fgets to populate the array in the above function?

> The file name is "Names.txt", and has the following content, not ignoring the numbering:

1. charlie
2. scarlett Johansson
3. saint nicholas santa claus

This is the information I want to use fgets (not including the numbering) into the array called Names[3][50], how do I do that?

Comment: Since you are dealing with an array of strings, skip the seconds loop and change `fgets()` to `fgets(Names[i], 50, file);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you I understand that you are dealing with an array of strings, if so each string can hold up to 48 characters, (49 if you get rid of the `'\n'` `fgets()` adds).
This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
#define MAX_LEN 50
#define MAX_LINES 3


int readMovies(FILE *file, char Names[3][50]) {

  int i;

  FILE *file = fopen("Names.txt", "r")
  if (myFile == NULL) {
      printf("Error");
      exit(-1);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < MAX_LINES; i++) {
    fgets(Names[i],MAX_LEN, file);
  }
/* ... */
}
```